# Extract matplotlib colormap in hex-format

Tags: python, matplotlib, hex, color-mapping, colormap

I am trying to extract discrete colors from a matplotlib colormap by manipulating [this example](http://matplotlib.org/1.2.1/examples/pylab_examples/poormans_contour.html). However, I cannot find the `N` discrete colors that are extracted from the colormap.

In the code below I've used `cmap._segmentdata`, but I've found that it is the definition of the entire colormap. Given a colormap and an integer `N`, how do I extract `N` discrete colors from the colormap and export them in hex-format?

```
from pylab import *

delta = 0.01
x = arange(-3.0, 3.0, delta)
y = arange(-3.0, 3.0, delta)
X,Y = meshgrid(x, y)
Z1 = bivariate_normal(X, Y, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0)
Z2 = bivariate_normal(X, Y, 1.5, 0.5, 1, 1)
Z = Z2 - Z1 # difference of Gaussians

cmap = cm.get_cmap('seismic', 5)    # PiYG
cmap_colors = cmap._segmentdata

def print_hex(r,b,g):
               if not(0 <= r <= 255 or 0 <= b <= 255 or 0 <= g <= 255):
                              raise ValueError('rgb not in range(256)')
               print '#%02x%02x%02x' % (r, b, g)


for i in range(len(cmap_colors['blue'])):
               r = int(cmap_colors['red'][i][2]*255)
               b = int(cmap_colors['blue'][i][2]*255)
               g = int(cmap_colors['green'][i][2]*255)
               print_hex(r, g, b)



im = imshow(Z, cmap=cmap, interpolation='bilinear',
            vmax=abs(Z).max(), vmin=-abs(Z).max())
axis('off')
colorbar()

show()
```

Answer (score 120, accepted):

You can get a tuple of rgba values for the segment with index `i` by calling `cmap(i)`. There is also already a function that turns rgb values into hex. As Joe Kington wrote in the comments, you can use `matplotlib.colors.rgb2hex`. Therefore, a possible solution would be:

```
from pylab import *

cmap = cm.get_cmap('seismic', 5)    # PiYG

for i in range(cmap.N):
    rgba = cmap(i)
    # rgb2hex accepts rgb or rgba
    print(matplotlib.colors.rgb2hex(rgba))
```

The output is:

```
#00004c
#0000ff
#ffffff
#ff0000
#7f0000
```

Comment: or using list comprehension [matplotlib.colors.rgb2hex(c) for c in cmap.colors]

Answer (score 6):

For future reference: My CMasher package provides a function called `take_cmap_colors()` (https://cmasher.readthedocs.io/user/usage.html#taking-colormap-colors), which allows one to take any number of discrete colors from a given colormap and return them in any format (8-bit, normalized or HEX) they want.

So, if you for example wanted to take 5 colors in HEX from the `viridis` colormap, you could do this with:

```py
import cmasher as cmr

colors = cmr.take_cmap_colors('viridis', 5, return_fmt='hex')
```

or if you want all colors in HEX from a colormap in a specific value range, you can do that with:

```py
colors = cmr.take_cmap_colors('viridis', None, cmap_range=(0.2, 0.8), return_fmt='hex')
```

Answer (score 0):

As `cm.get_cmap` [is getting deprecated since Matplotlib version 3.7](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/cm_api.html#matplotlib.cm.get_cmap), you can do

```
import matplotlib as mpl
import numpy as np

for step in np.linspace(0, 1, 5):
    print(mpl.colors.rgb2hex(cmap(step)))
```