# How to return legend data from matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, gis, shapefile, geopandas

I created a dataframe from shapefile using geopandas and then plotted using the gdf.plot function.
I want the color values assigned to the categories of data in the following format or similar:

```
{'1':'black(or color hex code)', 
'2':'color/#hexcode'....,
'7':'color/#hexcode'}
```

The plot is created using the following code:

```
plot = geodataframe.plot(
               column='map_c',
               categorical=True,
               legend=True,
               ax=ax,
               cmap='Accent_r')
```

[image: Output of the code]

Is it possible to get this metadata from the plot?

Comment: `h, l = plot.get_legend_handles_labels()` and then `{label: h[i].get_facecolor().tolist()[0] for i, label in enumerate(l)}`

Comment: `h, l = plot.get_legend_handles_labels()`  returns 2 empty lists

Comment: You're going to need to include a more complete [mre] with sample data then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a workaround I found out using pylab

```
from pylab import cm
from matplotlib.colors import rgb2hex

cmap = cm.get_cmap('Accent_r', 7) #7 categories I had
plot = geodataframe.plot(
               column='map_c',
               categorical=True,
               legend=True,
               ax=ax,
               cmap= cmap)
hexes = [rgb2hex(cmap(i)) for i in range(cmap.N)]
```

Refering to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33597599/15408580